# Breakable tcolorbox in beamer does not break automatically, and following questions

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I have encountered several problems when using a breakable `tcolorbox` with `beamer` class. For some of them, although workarounds are found, I still wonder if there exist more automatic and elegant solutions.

For the following questions, assume document class `beamer` is used and option `allowframebreaks` is added to `frame` environment.

**Question 1**. How to let breakable `tcolorbox` break automatically?

Workaround 1: Set `break at=<length1>` manually.

**Question 2**. How to vertically center *middle* parts (if any) of break sequence? (The *first* and *last* parts is vertically centered as expected.}

Workaround: Set `enlarge top at break by=<length2>` and `break at=<length1>/<length1 + length2>` to enlarge the topsep of middle and last parts and keep the height of text content of those parts unchanged. But this also adds topsep of last, which results to un-satisfied positioning.

It fails to pass any rubber length to key `enlarge top at break by` so I have to use something like "80pt" to simulate a vertical centering. How can I add something like `\vfill` before and after middle parts? There is a key named `vfill before first=<bool>` for first part, but not any similar keys for middle parts.

**Question 3**. How to add reminding text like "continued" before break?

Workaround: Use `bottomsep at break=<length>` for making some space, and `finish first and middle=<graphical code>` for adding reminding text.

**Question 4**. In general, how can I insert codes before and after breaks for first, middle, and last parts separately, to change their geometry, text contents and others?

The doc of `extras={<options>}` key family says

> Geometry and break settings should not be used here, ...

Hence `extras` key family is not suitable here. The `<code>` passed to keys `before` and `after`

> are used only before the first and after the last part of the break sequence.

Hence these two keys are not suitable as well.

---

A MWE to produce pages under all circumstances:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}

\tcbset{breakable}

\newcommand{\frameDemo}{
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \begin{tcolorbox} \lipsum[2-3] \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
% without any workarounds
\frameDemo

\tcbset{
  % workaround for question 1
  break at=100pt,
}
\frameDemo

\tcbset{
  % workaround for question 1 & 2
  break at=100pt/180pt,
  enlarge top at break by=80pt,
}
\frameDemo

\tcbset{
  % workaround for question 1, 2 & 3
  finish first and middle={
    \node[anchor=south east] 
        at ([xshift=-2pt]interior.south east) 
        {\itshape continued};
  },
  bottomsep at break=.7\baselineskip
}
\frameDemo

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont empty page
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A helper to assemble these beamer pages:

```
\documentclass[landscape, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-2,16,16,16,3-6,16,7-10,16,11-15}, nup=5x5, frame, delta=5 5]{breakable-in-beamer-texsx.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Screenshoot of assembled beamer pages:
[image: screenshoot]

Comment: You are misusing beamer. Presentations shouldn't contain long continous text parts. Design your slides one by one.  allowframebreak can be used for exceptions like a bibliography.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509208