# Breakable tcolorbox inside a Beamer slide

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I would like to have a tcolorbox **Example** with the option ***breakable*** that can be display in few beamer slide. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\newcounter{myexpl}[section]
\def\themyexpl{\thesection.\arabic{myexpl}}

\tcbmaketheorem{texample}{Example}{
fonttitle={\bfseries\upshape\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue!10!white}},
  fontupper=\slshape, arc=0mm, colback=red!50!yellow!5!white, 
colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black, separator sign dash,breakable} 
  {myexpl}{exp}
%
\title{Beamer Template}
\author{Test}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,allowframebreaks]{Example Breakable Test}
\begin{texample}{test}{tt}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{texample}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52386/54817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a really elegant solution (yet?) but shows that this can be done in principle. The key ingredient is [Martin Scharrer's solution of a closely related problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22836). The strategy is to save the `tcolorbox` in a `\savebox` and then to decompose it into bits that fit. Ironically, for this we do *not* need `breakable`. I also added some analog of the `\textheight`, called `\Textheight`, by hand simply because I do not know what the corresponding length really is.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\newcounter{myexpl}[section]
\def\themyexpl{\thesection.\arabic{myexpl}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newsavebox{\mysavebox}
\newlength{\myrest}
\newlength{\Textheight}
\Textheight=7.9cm
\newif\iffirstframe
\firstframetrue
\tcbmaketheorem{texample}{Example}{
fonttitle={\bfseries\upshape\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue!10!white}},
  fontupper=\slshape, arc=0mm, colback=red!50!yellow!5!white, 
colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black, separator sign dash} 
  {myexpl}{exp}
%
\title{Beamer Template}
\author{Test}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{lrbox}{\mysavebox}%
\begin{texample}{test}{tt}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{texample}
\end{lrbox}%
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,allowframebreaks]{Example Breakable Test}
\ifdim\ht\mysavebox>\Textheight
    \setlength{\myrest}{\ht\mysavebox}%
    \loop\ifdim\myrest>\Textheight
        \iffirstframe
         \firstframefalse
        \else 
         \newpage\par\noindent
        \fi 
        \clipbox{0 {\myrest-\Textheight} 0 {\ht\mysavebox-\myrest}}{\usebox{\mysavebox}}%
        \addtolength{\myrest}{-\Textheight}%
    \repeat
     \newpage\par\noindent 
    \clipbox{0 0 0 {\ht\mysavebox-\myrest}}{\usebox{\mysavebox}}%
\else
    \usebox{\mysavebox}%
\fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe that this will work for mdframed, too, cf. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52386/194703).

Comment: Thanks to @Schrödinger'sCat. The solution proposed works. I also found that `texemple` with `breakable` works outside a Frame.