# Splitting longtblr across beamer frames

Tags: beamer, tabularray

I've seen nowhere an option to split a `longtblr` into several beamer frames, does this feature exists ?

If not, is there a mean to perform this ?

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{counter} %% added this line

\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
    \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=blue2}
    \SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red2}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        
       \begin{longtblr}[
            theme = fancy,
            caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
            entry = {Short Caption},
            label = {tblr:test},
            note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
            note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
            remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
            remark{Source} = {Made up by myself. Made up by myself. Made up by myself.},
            ]{
             colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\linewidth,
             rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
             row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
             row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
            }
            \hline
            Head & Head & Head \\
            \hline
            Head & Head & Head \\
            \hline
            Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
            \hline
            Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a} & Eta \\
            \hline
            Iota & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
            \hline
            Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
            \hline
            Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
            \hline
            Phi & Chi & Psi \\
            \hline
            Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
            \hline
            Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
            \hline
            Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
            \hline
            Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
            \hline
            Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
            \hline
            Phi & Chi & Psi \\
            \hline
            Foot & Foot & Foot \\
            \hline
        \end{longtblr}
        
        
        \frametitle{TEST}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manually split the table using `\pagebreak`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{counter} %% added this line

\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
    \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=blue2}
    \SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red2}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
        
       \begin{longtblr}[
            theme = fancy,
            caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
            entry = {Short Caption},
            label = {tblr:test},
            note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
            note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
            remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
            remark{Source} = {Made up by myself. Made up by myself. Made up by myself.},
            ]{
             colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\linewidth,
             rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
             row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
             row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
            }
            \hline
            Head & Head & Head \\
            \hline
            Head & Head & Head \\
            \hline
            Alpha & Beta & Gamma\\
            \hline
            Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a} & Eta \\
            \hline
            Iota & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
            \hline
            Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
            \hline
            Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
            \hline
            Phi & Chi & Psi \\
            \hline
            Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\\pagebreak
            \hline
            Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
            \hline
            Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
            \hline
            Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
            \hline
            Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
            \hline
            Phi & Chi & Psi \\
            \hline
            Foot & Foot & Foot \\
            \hline
        \end{longtblr}
        
        
        \frametitle{TEST}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but that supposes that you know **when** to break page. Here this table is printed via a macro so I don't know in advance its length and if it needs to be splitted.

Comment: @3isenHeim Have a look if you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509263/36296